# Parse string into an array when it's already written like an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing

I'm reading a text file with XMLHttpRequest. Its contents are:

```
['01.html', '02.html', '03.html']
```

`xhr.responseText` is a string, and I can't cast it into an array, even though it is written precisely like an array.

In particular, `JSON.parse` does not work, because the strings here use single quotes (`'...'`), while the JSON grammar only recognizes string with double quotes (`"..."`).

Comment: Where's your code? Does `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` not work?

Comment: Any chance you have access to the server code to fix it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard it surely does not.

Comment: `eval(xhr.responseText)` will work if you understand the potential drawbacks and security issues

Comment: @Blorgbeard `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` produces an array of 1 string instead of an array of 3.

Comment: I edited your question to include an explanation why `JSON.parse` doesn't work, to reduce confusion for people who may not understand the issue at first. Please feel free to edit or remove it as you like.

Comment: Oh, right, double-quotes only in JSON. You could `replace("'",'"')`, then parse, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase you are persistence over `JSON.parse`.

This is how you can do it. Basically, like you said, reformat the string array and surround each element with a set of `"` double quotes and then parse it.

```js
var test = "['01.html', '02.html', '03.html']".replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(JSON.parse(test));
```